# Why in my WPF view is the Content text of my Label control not visible?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following markup:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding OrgListVisibility}">
        <Label Content="Org:" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OrgSelectList, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedItem="{Binding OrgId}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding BranchListVisibility}">
        <TextBlock Text="Branch:" Style="{StaticResource FormLabel}" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="BranchList" ItemsSource="{Binding BranchSelectList}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedItem="{Binding BranchId}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Yet when I run the app, only the text from the `TextBlock` is visible, and not that of the `Label`. The latter is in the Visual Tree, with a `TextBlock` deep down, but that is as far as I can see.

**AS REQUESTED:** Here is the style for `FormLabel`:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="FormLabel">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

**A SIMILAR PROBLEM:** 
I found an almost similar problem with a combobox when I bound it to a collection of instances of a generic class. The items' text simply did not show, but they were present in the comboboxes. Selecting on the one by knowing the position of my sought item correctly cascaded to the 2nd combobox, which had visible items, and I could see the correct but invisible item had been selected.

As soon as I change the item source to a list of non-generic objects, the items in the dropdown were visible again.

Comment: Is your ComboBox next to Label Visible?

Comment: @Vijay, yes. It's not the `OrgListVisibility` that matters, even before I bound the visibility the `Label` wasn't visible.

Comment: Assuming you are able to see Label in Visual tree as well. Is there any style defined which targets Label controls in resources? If not, try assigning the same Style to Label that you applied to TextBlock below.

Comment: For starters, +1 to solve the questionable downvote. As for the question, I'd ask if there's anything going on higher in the tree that might interact with a ContentControl and it's bound parts (like Content) that might interfere in an unexpected way since Label inherits from ContentControl and TextBlock is framework element? In most cases personally I just use TextBlock since it's lighter but I know that's irrelevant to the question. So I would be curious to see what other context is happening before it gets to rendering this portion.

Comment: Is Live Visual Tree available in WPF?

Comment: Could you post the style FormLabel? I copied your code and I can see the label. Maybe its the style causing the problem.

Comment: @user2837961 I have added the `FormLabel` style, but it is surely irrelevent. That style is only applied to the `TextBlockl`, and that is working; it's the `Label` that iisn't working.

Comment: Is only the text of the Label invisible or is the whole Label collapsed? E.g. do you see some empty space where the label should be or is this occupied by the ComboBox?

Comment: This works as it is for me, with your XAML snippet inside a `Grid`. I would inspect the **Design View** and verify if by any chance your `Label` is _sliding_ out-of-bounds. In case you can, post the full XAML context where the problem happens. Or as they say around here, the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you still see the TextBlock if you remove Style="{StaticResource FormLabel}" ?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, it's just badly styled.

Comment: @mbger The `Label` does take up layout space, and I can select it and see its outline. Only the text is invisible.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload a minimal, complete, and cerifiable sample of your issue to for example OneDrive? Because based on the information you have provided here the issue is not reproducible  I am afraid. Try to create new window, paste in the markup you have posted here and run it. Then you will probably see the Label. If you don't, then create a new blank application and do the same.

Comment: For $&#%'s and giggles just to eliminate possibilities, Set foreground to Red or something to override the default. If the template of Label is the default one, and the space is taken by the control like you say...then this is indeed a difficult one to troubleshoot without being in front of the reproducible instance.

Comment: Can you post more of your XAML markup? Can you try to place the first Stackpanel (that contains the other two stackpanels) inside a ScrollViewer to see if this is a space issue?

Comment: Definitely a [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)-Task. Just check the label at runtime, look for `Foreground`, `Background`, `Visibility`, `Font***` properties and so on. If anything is different than expected, check the value source and continue from there.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine and as you have mentioned in the comments section that it takes layout space then it may very well happen that the color of your label and the background color of the containing layout be same.

To troubleshoot this, try giving some different background and foreground colors e.g. red or blue to the Label. Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried different foregrounds, with no effect, but will definitely try backgrounds as well now. There is no styling anywhere that sets any colour for foreground, so I doubt the Label's foreground is wrong. Please see my next edit, in about 2 - 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+Q -> Live Visual Tree

Then hit the "pick element" button and select your label. Check the following properties:

`Visibility`
`Opacity`
`Content`

Also check the child elements of the Label. Setting the Content should result in a tree like this:

[image: Label visual tree]

If a default style has changed the control template, you might not see the TextBlock as a child here. Also drill into the TextBlock and make sure it has the right Text property, then make sure it and all its parents have the right `Opacity` and `Visibility` . Also make sure that the inner TextBlock has space allocated to it by selecting it and turning on the highlighting feature in the live visual tree window.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code to see if it works?

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding OrgListVisibility}">
        <Label Content="Org:" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OrgSelectList, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="Key" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding OrgId}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding BranchListVisibility}">
        <TextBlock Text="Branch:" Style="{StaticResource FormLabel}" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="BranchList" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding BranchSelectList}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="Key" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding BranchId}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Label would take up layout space while **not** being visible when its `Visibility == Hidden`. You should check and make sure that your application does not define a global style (one with no Key) for `TargetType="Label"` where this value could be set:

```
<Style TargetType="Label"> !!!note that this has no 'Key' associated
      [...]
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
      [...]
</Style>
```

This would not need to be in the same xaml file in order to be automatically applied, you should check the global dictionary or any other ResourceDictionary linked in the file.

Comment: a quick fix that might work would be to just set the visibility to "Visible" on the label: '<Label Content="Org:" Visibility="Visible" />'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out that the label Height was too small. Increased the height and its content became visible.